# Report Viewer on asp.net page keeps asking for authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7.5, reportviewer

Report Viewer on asp.net page keeps asking for authentication

i have report viewer control on asp.net page, on my machine (IIS 7.5, windows 7) its working fine, but when i deployed it to another machine (IIS 7.5, Windows 7), every time i open the report viewer page, i keep getting a dialog to enter my credentials (username, password), and even if i enter the correct credentials, i get a blank page.

i tried impersonate windows credentials, but i did not work.

can anyone help me on this please??

Answer (score 3):

ok i solved it, it was because the /Reports is reserved, i just changed the URL of that page